# Why does my data jump to the top of my table whenever it's entered at the bottom?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have an Access 2003 database with several tables in it. Just recently, I began noticing a problem that I don't believe has been happening in the past. I try entering part numbers at the bottom most row of my table, but if I accidentally click on another part number in another row, the new part jumps to the top of my table.

At first I thought this was due to the table automatically alphabetizing my entry, however that is not the case because I have tried entering "dummy" data that starts with everything from A-Z as well as numbers. Regardless of the first character I use, the new entry jumps to the top. I simply want it to stay at the bottom of my table and integrate itself into the table alphabetically later (upon closing the table and opening a new instance of it).

Does anyone know why this may be happening and could give me some advice on how to fix it? I don't have any primary keys set within the table design view either.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any data macros running on the table in the background? Did you try Decompiling/Compact & Repairing the database?

Comment: Are there sorts on fields in which the new record's value is null? Table Property "Order By" is empty?